# Using Prometheus with SNMP Exporter and regex to format OctetStrings

Tags: regex, prometheus, snmp, octetstring

We running Prometheus with SNMP Exporter to scrape SNMP targets. One target uses a large number of OctetStrings. What we'd like to achieve is overriding the OctetStrings to DisplayStrings and then using regex to retrieve the label as the metric.

The MIB looks as follows:
[The MIB file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dR3Nj.png)

For now we'll only focus on cfgProductName, cfgSoftwareVersion and cfgMIBVersion.

- For cfgProductName we'll add overrides for the type from OctetString
  to DisplayString and a regex to return the label value of
  cfgProductName as the metric. The regex we used is adapted from [the Grafana regex use here](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/variables/filter-variables-with-regex/) and tested [on regex101](https://regex101.com). We confirmed that the regex yields the result we're after.
- For cfgSoftwareVersion we'll add overrides for the type from OctetString
  to DisplayString and a simple regex just to test that the regex is doing something.
- For cfgMIBVersion we just change type from OctetString to
  DisplayString with no regex.

Our generator.yml file looks as follows:
[The generator.yml file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iitk5.png)

The resulting SNMP.yml looks as follows:
[The SNMP.yml file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cfdx5.png)

We use the resulting SNMP.yml in the SNMP Exporter to scrape the target.

The results are as follows:

- For cfgProductName, Prometheus allows autocomplete of the search string indicating that the scrape is in the DB, but returns an empty query result.
- For cfgSoftwareVersion, Prometheus doesn't allow autocomplete of the search string, suggesting that no scrape was performed.
- For cfgMIBVersion, the OctetString is changed to a DisplayString as we expected and Prometheus returns a result.[cfgMIBVersion query result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/14lsh.png)

We were expecting to see e.g. cfgProductNameValue with a metric equal to the result of the regex. Any suggestions on where we're going wrong?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Although you described your problem very detailed which is good, have a look at [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). It is hard to read when you have to follow links and pictures here and there. Try to post all the necessary informations and the content of your links as text or code or embed the picture at least directly in the question.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I'm not allowed to embed pictures until I reach 10 reputation points but next time I'll embed the code snippets :-)

Comment: The way  to solve this problem is to skip the regex_extract sections and to to check, what the exporter really returns (e.g.the output of something like `curl -s 'http://localhost:9116/snmp?compact&module=test&target=myDeviceIPorFQDN'`).